# StackExchange Data Explorer bug (PRIMARY filegroup full)

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

While trying to execute a query in the **StackExchange Data Explorer** I got the following:

[image: bug screenshot]

Comment: This was mentioned in chat a couple hours ago; I think they're working on it

Comment: @MichaelMrozek So is it a duplicated question? `:)`

Comment: Indeed we've hit a space issue on the old server this runs on...hardware is on the way to give us some breathing room.  SO we watch closely...the data explorer less so since it's updated...well, not every second.  We've grown quite a bit, and the data explorer DB server in OR needs some extra space added to cope.

Comment: That's what I thought.

Answer (score 6):

I put out the fire and am sorting out a more sustainable solution.

Turns out 300gigs is not enough for a full db backup for SE and family with an additional copy for data.se