# Related Questions not entirely related/useful

Tags: discussion, feature-request, search, related-questions

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90573/error-on-stack-exchange-data-explorer was posted (and quickly marked as a dupe and deleted so 10k only) and was a dupe of [StackExchange Data Explorer bug (PRIMARY filegroup full)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90564/stackexchange-data-explorer-bug-primary-filegroup-full) which is cool, cos people don't always read, but so I tried using the title from the dupe as the header for a new question, and it didn't show the dupe-original in the list of proposed related questions.

---

## The point I'm making

The Related Questions query seems to need some loving. Won't you please love on the Related Questions query so that it can faster find the more recent posts as well as the more upvoted ones?

Comment: Are you suggesting that recent and highly-scored questions have a higher relevance score than the concept-matching it does now?  If so, that could be problematic.  How do we know that the balance it has struck now is actually bad?

Comment: @Renesis that's kind of what I'm asking tbh

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps we could filter out dupes from the list anyway, even if we do nothing more sophisticated than that?

For example, is it actually useful to advertise [this six-year-old duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17367/when-voting-an-answer-down-is-it-polite-to-add-a-comment-giving-a-reason?rq=1)? Will its surprising score of 18 and its surprising answer count of 28 be increased by this unwarranted attention?