# Data Explorer PRIMARY filegroup full

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

Same as [this from 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90564/stackexchange-data-explorer-bug-primary-filegroup-full), I'm getting:

[image: Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.CachedResults' in database 'Data.StackExchange' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup or setting autogrowth on existing files in the filegroup.]

trying to run any of the [progress-towards-generalist](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/35591/generalist-progression-updated) queries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah, [according to Nick](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6771/data-se-still-calls-us-gaming#comment18236_6773), the behemoth that is Stack Overflow apparently ate up all of the disk space used for the import:

> we are ordering more drive space for the SO import, it went boom this weekend due to growth....oops.

I assume that this is related. <s>Hopefully something can be done to free up space until the new disks arrive.</s> Nick gave it a kick and you should be good to go now.

Comment: Hurrah! Thanks Nick!